# UITableView respond when user taps the plus button to insert row

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

What method do I use to know when a user has tapped the "add new row" green plus button in my UITableView?

Comment: Do you have a function that is getting called when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the "Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections" section of the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    //your code here
    NSLog(@"user tapped insertion control");
    }   
}
```